# Is it possible to set a default alert for new events in Google Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar, notifications

Is it possible to set a default alert for new events in Google Calendar?

For example, every new event I put in Google Calendar I always set alerts as follows:

- 15 mins
- 45 mins
- 2 hours
- 1 day

At the moment I manually have to add each alert to each new event. Is it possible to have these set as a default?

Comment: Related answer: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/172024/87075

Answer (score 1):

1. On [Google Calendar](https://calendar.google.com/), click `Settings` (top right) > `Settings`
2. Go to `Settings for my calendars` (left menu) > "My calendar name" > `Event notifications`
3. Under `Event notifications` and/or `All-day event notifications` > click `Add notification` and select the type and time frame of your notifications.
4. Add more if needed

See more on the **For specific calendars** section on [Modify Google Calendar notifications](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37242?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop#zippy=%2Cturn-notifications-on-or-off)

Answer (score -1):

Go to "settings" on the left under "my calendars" in the main view. Click on the "notifications" link. Select your preference in the drop down menus in "Event Reminders".

See [Modify Google Calendar notifications](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37242?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop#zippy=%2Cturn-notifications-on-or-off)

Comment: @Ricardo This answer is obsolete, adding the link to the help article, should be paired with updating the answer or you post an answer according to the last changes done to Google Calendar.

Comment: Ponsfrilus : You might update your answer to match the current Google Calender user interface / terminology.

Comment: @Rubén added a new answer instead