# How can I disable alert notifications for Focus Time events on Google Calendar?

Tags: google-workspace, google-calendar, notifications

I use [Focus time](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/11190973?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop) on my calendar to give my colleagues a reference of when to schedule meetings, so I have a separate time for individual contribution. This is only available for Google Workspace Accounts. But I don't need notifications for these events and I couldn't find a way to disable them. Currently there aren't any knobs for **Focus time** on:

- globally: `Settings` > `Event settings`
- globally: `Settings` > `Notification settings`
- specific recurrent event > `Edit event`

Here is the official support page: [Modify Google Calendar notifications](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37242?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop#zippy=%2Cturn-notifications-on-or-off)

Answer (score 1):

My workaround to the missing knob is to **remove notifications globally on my calendar** and only add notifications to my events when needed:

1. On [Google Calendar](https://calendar.google.com/), click `Settings` (top right) > `Settings`
2. Go to `Settings for my calendars` (left menu) > "My calendar name" > `Event notifications`
3. Under `Event notifications` and `All-day event notifications` > click `Remove notification`.
4. *[Optional]* When needed, select a calendar event > `Edit event` and `Add notification`; or when adding an event, `More options` > `Add notification`

See more on the **For specific calendars** section on [Modify Google Calendar notifications](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37242?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop#zippy=%2Cturn-notifications-on-or-off)